# Dynamically append data inside <div> angular6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a template : 
`<div class='somedata'></div>`
I want to append a list of `<div>` dynamically one after the other . 
Data i fetch using a shared service through a `Subject` .

For Example :

```
<div class='somedata'>
<div id='dynamicdata1'>some data</div>
<div id='dynamicdata2'>some data</div>
..
..
..
</div>
```

`dynamicdata1` , `dynamicdata2` etc arrive one after the other with some delay .

Initially i thought of using an `ngFor` to render the `div`, but everytime i push a data into the `ngFor` bound variable , the loop runs again due to angular's `changeDetection` .

Is there any way this can be solved without using `*ngFor` ?

I know there is a way using jQuery where we can use `$(selector).append()` but is there anyway this can be done in angular?

Thanks ,

Comment: If you use a custom trackBy function, you can use ngFor to append new divs to the list.

Comment: @trichetriche can you help me out with an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment, here is an example of a custom trackBy function :

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y; trackBy: customTB"></div>


customTB(index, item) {
  return item.id;
}
```

If the value returned by your function doesn't change, then the items won't move from your view when it is updated. So by giving new items to your array, and by returning only their ID, you will append items to the arrat, without moving the others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `innerHTML` to append some data into HTML element as per your requirements.

Comment: ``<div>`` that has dynamic data is unknown until i get the data i.e i have no clue if i have ``<div id='dynamicdata1'>`` . so i have to use innerHtml and re render the whole ``<div class='somedata'>`` everytime a new data arriveswhich i want to avoid